# Python: How to import a function written in a file in another directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a folder called *test* and inside of that, I have 2 folders: *functions* and *code*. 
In *functions*, I have a file called `hello.py` which has a method called `say_hello()`. 
In *code*, I have a file called `main.py`, where I want to use `say_hello()`.

The structure is like this:

```
test/functions/hello.py
test/code/main.py
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `sys.path.append('/path/to/application/program/folder')` would be the perfect and easy way

Answer (score 1):

You should approach the project structure a bit differently. This is a basic example of how you could do it:

```
test/
│
├── test/ # your code goes here
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── functions/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── hello.py
│       └── byebye.py
|
|   # examples of what you can keep here:
├── LICENSE
└── README
```

Then in main.py you could import and use *hello.py* like this:

```py
from functions import hello

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # above condition is true if you launch the script directly
    # (e.g. by double clicking its file)
    hello.say_hello()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append the path and then you can import

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/application/program/folder')
```

and or

```
from test.functions import hello
from test.code import main
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solving this problem without relative imports and without using sys.path:

Folder Structure:

```bash
root/
   serve/
       - app.py
   src/
       - utils.py
```

To access functions of utils.py in app.py, use:
`from src.utils import function`

Running from root:
`python -m serve.app`

[instead of `python serve/app.py`]

`-m mod` allows to run library module as a script.

You can change name of the imports based on your structure.